# All Application URLs for MIME type

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, launch-services

Besides `LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL` there exists `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL` to get all applications, not just the default one.

If you just want to get default applications for a MIME type, there is `LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForContentType`, but it doesn't seem to have an equivalent to get all supported applications.

How can I get all supported applications for a MIME type, without having an actual file on disk?

Comment: I think `LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks that way. Thanks! (if I were you I would have posted that as an answer and collected that sweet sweet rep nectar)

Comment: Well, honestly, I wasn't 100% sure that was the answer. ;) But it if is, I'll take the credit ... answer posting shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType` will return a list of application bundle IDs that are registered to handle a particular content type (using a UTI).

The logical difference between this function and `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL` is that the list can be filtered to just those applications that handle said content in a particular way (display-only, edit, etc.). If you want all of the applications, pass `kLSRolesAll`.

To obtain the actual application URL(s), call `LSCopyApplicationURLsForBundleIdentifier` with one of the returned app IDs.